# How to add vertical space between JButton in BoxLayout?

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

I have panel  with 2 buttons in BoxLayout. What i  want is  to add  vertical space between the buttons.

[image: Sreenshot:]

Here is my code:

```
frame = new JFrame("FreshPos baza podataka");
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);          

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 5, 0, 0));
panel.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);       
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

panel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10) );    

JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");     
panel.add(btnNewButton_1);              

JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");                 
panel.add(btnNewButton_2);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an invisible vertical component to the panel in between the two buttons:

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
panel.add(btnNewButton_1);

panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(50));

JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
panel.add(btnNewButton_2);
```